# How to associate one user to multiple dealerships with specific role at each dealership in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET Identity, how to associate one user to multiple locations (let's say dealerships) and assign a specific role for that user at each dealership?

Answer (score 1):

Claims

You can define a claim for a user, which is just a key-value pair.  So, for instance, you could have their dealership number as a claim, and have the dealership number be a claim, with the role as the value.  Or you could have a  Dealership1-role and the value would be Administrator, or whatever you want to do.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Another option is to create specific roles for each dealership.  Ie. Dealer1-Admin and assign that to the user.